# Not able to understand fork() system call clearly?

Tags: operating-system, fork, system-calls

There are multiple questions about fork() on SO and I have been reading them for quite a while. I am trying to solve this trick question which states like this:

```
Consider the code fragment:
if(fork==0)
{a = a+5; printf("%d, %d \n", a, &a);}
else{a = a-5; printf("%d, %d \n", a, &a);}

Let u, v be the values printed by the parent process and x, y be the values printed by the child process. Which of the following is true:

a) u = x+10 and v = y
b) u = x+10 and v != y
c) u+10 = x and v = y
d) u+10 = x and v != y
```

Obviously, the addresses of parent and child process are different so the answer has to be either b or d. I am not able to interpret even how `u` can be `x+10` or `u+10` can be `x`. How exactly does this work? `fork()` creates two exact copies of the processes. If the `fork()` returns zero, it means the parent is executing in the `if` block. Otherwise, the child executes the statement in the `else` block and then the parent executes in the `if` block? Is my line of thought correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my line of thought correct?

Almost.

> `fork()` creates two exact copies of the processes.

> Obviously, the addresses of parent and child process are different

These two statements contradict. There is no "reloading" of the process after the fork, therefore *all addresses must be the same*. This is possible due to the MMU of the CPU creating a distinct virtual address space for each process, and is one of the primary reasons why the kernel must be heavily modified in order to run on a CPU without one.

> If the `fork()` returns zero, it means the parent is executing in the `if` block.

`fork()` returns the new child's PID in the parent, and 0 in the child.